# C++ command line prompt shouldn't repeat

Tags: c++, io, command-line-arguments

My program takes input from the command line, and should be able to process both single and multiple character commands like this:

```
prompt> A  
A response
prompt> AB  
A response  
B response
```

But right now my program behaves like this:

```
prompt> AB
A response
prompt>
B response
```

How can I structure the loop to fix this?
Right now I have:

```
for(;;)
  cout << prompt
  cin >> command
  // error checking
  switch(command) { ... }
```

Comment: What about just not repeating the `cout << prompt` line. BTW as is you example doesn't even compile.

Comment: spec calls for user prompt before every command or series of commands. and yes i just wanted to illustrate the point

Comment: Your question (problem) is completely unclear, but I guess you'll need `std::getline(std::cin,command);` instead of `std::cin >> command;` and parse `command` from a whole line.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I structure the loop to fix this?

One way to do that would be to:

1. Read the input as a token.
2. Iterate over the characters of the token
3. Process each charater as you see fit.

---

```
std::string token;
std::cout << prompt;
std::cin >> token;
for ( char command : token )
{
   switch(command) { ... }
}
```

If you would like to be able treat white space characters as commands, it will be necessary to use `std::getline` to read a line of text and iterate over the characters of the line.

```
std::string line;
std::cout << prompt;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
for ( char command : line )
{
   switch(command) { ... }
}
```

Comment: `getline` might be a better choice here in case whitespace can be a command.

Comment: in this case, we can assume no whitespace, so the first solution worked perfectly. thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderWisowaty, you're welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming command is declared as a char your code is doing exactly what you say.

```
for(;;)
  cout << prompt // prompt user types AB
  cin >> command  // read one char A
  // error checking
  switch(command) { ... } // process it
}
```

Now loop back and reprompt.

You need

```
for(;;)
{
  cout << prompt
  cin >> commandString // std::string
  for(auto command : commandString) // loop over each char
  {
   switch(command) { ... }
  }
}
```